# How to I determine what's causing the exception "This is an invalid webresource request."

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

This is possibly a dupe.  See my note at the end of this question *before flagging this as a duplicate question*.

All of a sudden Since October of 2013 (last year), ELMAH has been reporting `This is an invalid webresource request`.  I cannot figure out what is causing this issue.  It has probably occurred 50 or so times and its occurrence appears completely random.  Oddly, this error is generated by a small handful of the same repeat users and always occurs on the same page.  I've tried navigating to the same page using the same query string as they do and I am not able to reproduce this issue.

Some research has led me to [this page](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/07-03-27/debugging-asp-net-2-0-web-resources-decrypting-the-url-and-getting-the-resource-name.aspx) where a guy offers a solution to figuring out the offending resource.  However, when I copy the file to the production server and paste in the WebResource.axd query string, the try/catch catches `TargetInvocationException` and does nothing.

I'd rather have a solution that does not involve contacting these users.

**Note about the dupe**

I am not sure how to handle this on SE.  There are other questions here that match this one, but they're old and either 1) have no answers that help my situation or 2) have no answers at all.  Additionally, their circumstances are not the same as mine.  The only option is to hijack their question by editing it and replacing the contents with my own, but that's not a good solution since the OPs may still be monitoring their questions.

Comment: Is there anything useful about the request in the ELMAH or IIS logs? URL, user agent, response code? Most likely it's just a browser plugin. If it were a problem for those users, they'd probably have contacted you already.

Comment: @CodeCaster I found nothing of interest in those.  What I ended up doing was adding the exceptions to my "ignored exception" list so that ELMAH stops reporting it.  I'll still leave the question open for anyone with the answer to this.